# If two cards are compared and the images have the same value, they disappear from the screen in memory game Online

Tags: javascript

I am making elmanism with js. Click on two cards from the 52 playing card images, and if the images have the same value, the two cards will disappear from the screen. If not, the card will return to its original state.I want to do this processing.

Even if I flip the cards, I can't compare the two cards.

Comment: Why not just compare a data-atribute between both and if equal you fade them out or something?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What exactly does it mean to compare data attributes? I added an id to the image element and compared a common string (here a number), is this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID shud be unique. You can have a data-value in your elementes, and then compare both. If they are equal you remove the dulicated.

Here is an ideia for what you need. It gets the first Card data-value and stores in variable, after it will get all other cards and compare their data-value, if they are equal it will remove the duplicated. Im using jQuery but you can use vanilla if you want.

```js
function deleteDuplicate(){
    
  var uniqueCardValue = $(".card:first").data('value');
    $('.card').each( function(index){
    if (index != '0'){
      var activeCardValue = $(this).data('value');
      if (activeCardValue == uniqueCardValue)
      {
          $(this).fadeOut();
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.container img {
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img class="card" data-value="card1" src="http://www.shorturl.at/wAQY0">
  <img class="card" data-value="card2" src="http://www.shorturl.at/fjrLM">
  <img class="card" data-value="card3" src="http://www.shorturl.at/eoAV3">
  <img class="card" data-value="card1" src="http://www.shorturl.at/wAQY0">
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="deleteDuplicate()">Delete duplicate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: To do with js, set the data attributes like this
const div = document.querySelector ('div')
div.dataset.age = "20" Shouldn't I do it?
To be honest, I've never touched jQuery.